# Change Screen Dim TimeOut

Tags: settings, screen

When the phone is idle, the screen turns off after the configured time. For ex: if time is set to 30 sec, first the screen will dim after approximately 25 seconds and then after 5 seconds it will turn off the screen completely.

How can I increase that "5" seconds time to 30 seconds or any other value?

Comment: There's no built-in way to do this, because the dim is there to warn you that the screen is about to turn off.

Comment: Different phone has different pattern of turn off screen. So, can you please tell me the name of your phone you are currently using?

Comment: Mine is a Samsung S3. I am sure there must be a timer where this count happens.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a custom ROM (like CyanogenMod) or stock Android go to `Settings>Display>Automatic backlight`. Click on enable and select the window length option to change the time according to your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately this option is not available on my ROM.

Comment: you can use apps like screebl from the playstore to manipulate the screen dimness but i am not sure about the time option in that...

Answer (score 1):

If you have source code of frameworks, you could modify dim duration in PowerManagerService:

```
private static final int SCREEN_DIM_DURATION = 7 * 1000;
private static final float MAXIMUM_SCREEN_DIM_RATIO = 0.2f;

private int getScreenDimDurationLocked(int screenOffTimeout) {
    return Math.min(SCREEN_DIM_DURATION,
            (int)(screenOffTimeout * MAXIMUM_SCREEN_DIM_RATIO));
}
```

The return value of getScreenDimDurationLocked() is what you want, you could modify it.

Below link is a post to solve this problem, I wrote in Chinese:

[CSDN Blog: Modify Android dim duration in frameworks](http://blog.csdn.net/zhoumushui/article/details/51443492)

I hope that would be useful for you.

Comment: Appreciate your efforts to provide a solution , but this is a *end user* site and programmatic questions and answers are not encouraged

Comment: Please see: [Should we delete answers that are purely programming solutions?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/2161/16575) I agree with beeshyams here (though I didn't downvote nor take any action on this). Android.SE is a site for end-users, so purely programming solutions do not really fit and thus should be absolute exceptions.